# Passing an element of an array of structs to a function

Tags: c++, c, function, struct

I tried this code, but it doesn't work. I want to send only the element `p` of the `struct grid`, not the whole struct to the function.

```
struct grid{ 
  int p; 
  int s; 
}

void create(int a[9][9]); 
{ 
  a[0][2] = 4; 
}

int main() 
{
  struct grid a[9][9]; 
  create(a.s); 
}
```

Comment: `int`, `int[][9]` are two different types. You can not intermix. To access the members of the array, you need to use `[]` operator.

Comment: Select a language and stick to it. C and C++ are two languages, count them.

Comment: There is no easy way to do what you are asking for in C without re-structuring your program.

Comment: C-style 2D arrays are a nightmare hack to be desperately avoided.

Comment: An element of array of structs is a struct. An element of a struct may be an integer. You cannot select an array of integers out of an array of structs.

Comment: The good news is that it really doesn't matter that you are passing the whole thing. C array get pass around as pointers, not full values, so its not like there is any surplus copying being done.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have three choices, switch to two matrices, put the dimensions in the struct, or have `create()` take an array of struct:

**Two arrays:**

```
void create(int a[9][9]) 
{ 
  a[0][2] = 4; 
}

int main() 
{
  int p[9][9];
  int s[9][9]; 
  create(s); 
}
```

-- or --  **put the dimensions in the struct:**

```
struct grid{ 
  int p[9][9]; 
  int s[9][9]; 
};

void create(int a[9][9])
{ 
  a[0][2] = 4; 
}

int main() 
{
  struct grid a; 
  create(a.s); 
}
```

-- or --  **Pass an array of struct**

```
struct grid{ 
  int p; 
  int s; 
};

void create(struct grid[9][9] * a) 
{ 
  (*a)[0][2].s = 4; 
}

int main() 
{
  struct grid a[9][9]; 
  create(&a); 
}
```

You cannot cherry pick elements out of an array or matrix of structs

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, what you need cannot be done in that way. One way to resolve the issue is to transform the matrix before passing it to the method:

```
using namespace std;

struct grid{ 
    int p; 
    int s; 
};

void create(int a[9][9])
{ 
    a[0][2] = 4; 
}

void ExtractS(struct grid a[9][9], int s[9][9])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            s[i][j] = a[i][j].s;
}

int main() 
{
    struct grid a[9][9]; 
    int s[9][9];
    ExtractS(a, s);
    create(s);
}
```

But this opens more questions than it answers:

- Data would have to be returned back into original matrix of structures, or otherwise change made by create is lost
- This method is very inefficient because it copies all the data

Maybe you should revise the design and make `create` function receive matrix of `grid` elements.

Comment: You could make the transform take a matrix of references to `int` instead if just `int`, that way changes aren't lost, but scoping can be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Initial Note:
`void create(int a[9][9])` turns in fact into
`void create(int a[][9])` or `void create(int (*a)[9])`

You may want `void create(int (&a)[9][9])`.

As you have
`struct grid { int p; int s; };` and `struct grid a[9][9];`

You should initialize like this:

```
void create(grid (&g)[9][9])
{
    g[0][2].s = 4;
}
```

or change your struct as

```
struct grid {
    int p[9][9];
    int s[9][9];
};
```

And then have

```
void create(grid &g)
{
    g.s[0][2] = 4;
}
```

or

```
void create(int (&a)[9][9])
{
    a[0][2] = 4;
}
```

that you call respectively `create(g)` and `create(g.s)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an integer to a function which expects a pointer to `2D array` as an argument,

The prototype for the function to accept the member variable `s` of structure `grid` as argument should be as follows,

```
void create(int a);
```

Also there is an unwanted semicolon in your program in the function definition.

```
void create(int a[9][9]); <-- No need
{ 
    a[0][2] = 4; 
}`
`
```

Comment: but I think he actually wants to send in the 9x9 of esses, not just one number, well spotted on the `;` tho.

Comment: There is a missing semicolon in his `struct` definition as well.